# Interface is not calling in fragment

Tags: android, interface, fragment

I have created an Interface in a common class. I have call the inteface function in Activity.I want to implement the interface method in fragment.

this is the inteface in Utility.java

```
 public interface CloseMenu{
    public void closemenu(View view);
}
```

This is how I am calling this interface in Activity:
declaration:

```
 public Utility.CloseMenu closeMenu;
```

initialization onCreate:

```
  closeMenu= (Utility.CloseMenu) this;
```

calling interface:

```
closeMenu.closemenu(view);
```

in fragment class I have implemented this Interface:

```
 @Override
    public void closemenu(View view) {
    view=mLoginFragmentView;
    slideDown(view);
   }
```

But I am getting crash as:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zinedroid.hospitalmanagement/com.zinedroid.hospitalmanagement.Activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zinedroid.hospitalmanagement.Activity.HomeActivity cannot be cast to com.zinedroid.hospitalmanagement.Common.Utility$CloseMenu

Can anyone Please help me?

Comment: I added the android tag to attract proficient users. Only talking about an "interface" can mean a lot of languages.

Comment: thank you.BUt Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: You are using `this` in the Activity - which is the Activity itself. It does not seem to implement `CloseMenu` interface. You probably want to set `closeMenu` field to the appropriate instance of the _Fragment_ that implements the interface instead?

Comment: Are you implementing the interface by the Activity?

Comment: @Reza I am implementing the inteface in fargment.But calling the interface instance in Activity

Comment: @Fildor I want call the closemenu in Activity Itself.And the interface should be implemented in fragment

Comment: Yes, but you need a reference to the fragment, because the fragment implements the interface. So you have the field `closeMenu` in the Activity. This is your reference with which you can call the interface method. But this reference must refer to an instance of a class that actually implements the interface. In this case that would be the fragment. So you call from the Activity into the Fragment.

Comment: show where you declare the class that implements your interface: `class <something> implements CloseMenu`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko public class BottomMenuFragment extends BaseFragment implements Utility.CloseMenu

Comment: @Fildor how can i create a reference to the fragment and implement it in fragment?

Comment: My last encounter with Android is somewhat outdated, so I don't know how you instanciate Fragments these days, but assuming _you know_: `closeMenu= (Utility.CloseMenu) this;` change to `closeMenu= (Utility.CloseMenu) fragment;`, where fragment is an instance of your BottomMenuFragment. Assuming it's in your Layout, you'll probaly need to use the FragmentManager and get it by Id or something alike.

Comment: _"Likewise, your activity can call methods in the fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag()."_ - See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: @Fildor I ve just instanciate fragment using   final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ft_menu = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft_menu.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slid_out_up);
                ft_menu.add(R.id.frame_menu, new BottomMenuFragment());
                ft_menu.commit();

Comment: There you go. Get it from the Manager as described in the link I posted in above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem.closemenu should be initialized in onAttach of the fragment which is implementing the fragment.

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    activity = getActivity();

    ((HomeActivity)activity).closeMenu = this;
}
```